# Join array items in loop with perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array with x items:

```
my @arr= qw( mother child1 child2 child3);
```

Now i want to ietrate this array. Every Loop should append an entry:

1. mother
2. mother/child1
3. mother/child1/child2
4. mother/child1/child2/child3

How i can realize this with perl?

Comment: You can do this recursively. Have you tryed anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this solution:

```perl
my @arr= qw( mother child1 child2 child );
my $content;
my $i;
foreach (@arr){
  $content .= '/' if ($content);
  $content .= $_;
  print "$i.$content\n";
  $i++;
}
```

The result as you expect.

#### output

```
.mother
1.mother/child1
2.mother/child1/child2
3.mother/child1/child2/child3
```

---

#### Update

That should have been

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @arr= qw( mother child1 child2 child3 );

my $content;
my $i = 1;

foreach ( @arr ) {

  $content .= '/' if $content;
  $content .= $_;

  print "$i.$content\n";

  ++$i;
}
```

#### output

```
1.mother
2.mother/child1
3.mother/child1/child2
4.mother/child1/child2/child3
```

Comment: I doubt if the OP requires the numbers printing before each path. In any case, `$content .= '/' if ($i>1)` is better written as `$content .= '/' if $content`, so the `$i` variable is unnecessary.

Comment: What you've written is very compact. Perl will ignore whitespace between tokens, so you should make the most of that to lay out your program so that it is readable. Also, please test your code before you post it. Look at the output from your (revised) code. If you had `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place as you should have then you would have seen the warning message ***Use of uninitialized value $i in concatenation (.) or string***

Comment: Please don't edit your posts so the earlier contributions make no sense.

Comment: @Borodin: I corrected it, I'm new to stackoverflow and very appreciate your prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more idiomatic solution.

```
my @arr = qw[mother child1 child2 child3];

say $_ + 1, '. ', join ('/', @arr[0 .. $_]) for 0 .. $#arr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the individual paths, or do you just want to join all the segments?

To do the latter you can just write

```
my $path = join '/', @arr;
```

(By the way, that's an awful identifier. The `@` tells us that it's an array so the `arr` adds nothing. I don't know what your data represents, but perhaps `@segments` would be better.)

But if you need the loop, you can do this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @arr= qw( mother child1 child2 child3 );

for my $i ( 0 .. $#arr ) {

    my $path = join '/', @arr[0 .. $i];

    say $path;
}
```

#### output

```
mother
mother/child1
mother/child1/child2
mother/child1/child2/child3
```

Note that this is essentially the same algorithm as [**Dave Cross** shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39387452/622310) but I have used a standard block `for` loop as I imagine that you will want to do something with the paths other than printing them, and I have removed the numbering as I think that was just an illustrative part of your question.